# Meaning of Empty Line in CSV File

Tags: csv

At first this seemed obvious, but now I'm not so sure.

If a CSV file has the following line:

```
a,
```

I would interpret that as two fields with the values "a" and "". But then looking at an empty line, I could just as easily argue that it signifies one field with the value "".

I accept that an empty line at the end of the file should be interpreted as the end of the file (no field). But does anyone have any information on what an empty line within the file should mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at how Excel handles empty lines when reading CSV files, I can see that Excel does *not* ignore them.

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell if the empty line was treated as an empty field or no fields at all because Excel always has the same number of columns.

I saw some proprietary uses of the CSV format where there was an option to how blank lines should be treated. In the end, this is the approach I took. My CSV reader class has four options for how to deal with empty lines:

1. Ignore and skip over them
2. Treat them as a row with zero fields
3. Treat them as a row with one empty field
4. Treat them as the end of the input file

If anyone's interested, I will be posting the new source code to replace the existing article at [Reading and Writing CSV Files in C#](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c).

Comment: +1 Considering how there's no enforced standard and every implementation is different, it is very possible that your parser will make an incorrect assumption about what you want.

Comment: you're a csv guru.. just out of curiosity though, in what ways are your csv classes here different from your post on code project? which would you recomend using, and why?http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

Comment: @iliketocode: The code on Black Belt Coder is newer. It includes a few fixes and has new features such as support for multi-line fields.

Comment: It is very simple to avoid this case if requiring that all empty fields (or at least if the first empty field is quoted) are quoted. RFC 4180 (as "standard as anyone gets") does not say anything about empty fields in regards..

Comment: @user2864740: That's all well and good, but anyone who processes CSV files knows that some may not be formatted correctly. So then the question is do you handle it as best you can or abort with an error. I think handling it generally has more value to the user. This is only an issue for malformed data. Correctly formed data will always work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Be aware that an empty line might be part of a multiline quoted field:

```
1,2,"this
is
field number

3",4,5
```

is valid CSV.

In most CSV files I've seen, the number of fields is constant per row (although that doesn't have to be so), so unless a CSV file only has one column, I would expect empty lines (outside of quoted fields) to be a mistake.

I just checked: Python's CSV parser ignores empty lines. I guess that's  reasonable.

Comment: Yes, I agree an empty line within a quoted field means a literal empty line. I'm more concerned with the case where it is not part of a quoted field.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my understanding and experience it stands for missing record and should be ignored. Don't treat it as EOF.

Comment: No, I certainly wouldn't treat it as EOF, except when it's a blank line at the end of the file. But I'm writing a CSV reader, so I don't know if it should it should return zero fields or one empty field for an empty line, or just skip over the empty line and don't even notify the caller that an empty line was encountered.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; After thinking about RFC, I would interpret empty line as a record with one empty value.

In RFC (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) there is a grammar. The grammar contains, among other things, this:

```
file = [header CRLF] record *(CRLF record) [CRLF]
...
record = field *(COMMA field)
...
field = (escaped / non-escaped)
non-escaped = *TEXTDATA
```

Strictly speaking, the grammar does not define the semantics, but anyway, I would interpret it so that a record has at least one field, possibly with empty value.

If I would write a grammar, where there could be a record without fields at all, I would write something different, maybe:

```
record = *fields CRLF
fields = field *(COMMA field)
```